# Is this possible for C to execute a piece of js code?

Tags: javascript, c, cross-language

For example, I have a js code, and I while like to write a simple console program that read this code, execute it, and print back the result. Is this possible to do so? If yes, how can I start doing this? Thank you.

Comment: look in to something like v8 or rhino...

Comment: is there anything related to dom in this js code?

Comment: Of course it's possible. It's called an interpreter. There's at least a dozen of them, likely more if you count non-mainstream ones.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Rhino is Java, isn't it?

Comment: @Thor84no Yea, I forgot about that. Even still, you could ship the Rhino jar with your C application and run the jar inside your application.

Comment: Yes, you could. But running a JVM to run a JS engine to interpret a script... It's all getting a little messier than it needs to be at that point.

Comment: I see. Thank you all, I will do some researches on this direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd need a JS engine for C such as [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey) (which is the one FireFox uses). I'm not sure how easy that is to use though, there may be others that are better.

Comment: This seems to be of interest: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_User_Guide